Transaction failed to sanitize accounts offsets correctly
I am using Solana Playground to write Solana code.I have written a simple Greeting struct with rust that has a counter field. When I try to interact with the contract using typescript I get this error
   failed to sanitize accounts offsets correctly] logs: undefined }

After doing console logs I realized it is due to the function sendAndConfirm in sayHello function. Everything else works perfectly. can anyone help me please
import * as borsh from 'borsh';
class GreetingAccount {
  counter = 0;
  constructor(fields: {counter: number} | undefined = undefined ) {
    if (fields) {
      this.counter = fields.counter;
    }
  }
}

const GreetingSchema = new Map([
  [GreetingAccount, {kind: 'struct', fields: [['counter', 'u32']]},]
])

const GREETING_SIZE = borsh.serialize (
  GreetingSchema,
  new GreetingAccount(),
).length;

let payer;
let programId;
let greetedPubkey;

async function establishPayer(): Promise<void> {
  payer = pg.wallet.keypair;
  let lamports = await pg.connection.getBalance(pg.wallet.publicKey);
  console.log(
    'Using account',
    payer.publicKey.toBase58(),
    'containing',
    lamports / web3.LAMPORTS_PER_SOL,
    'SOL to pay for fees'
  );
}

async function checkProgram(): Promise<void> {
programId = pg.wallet.publicKey;
  console.log(`Using program ${programId.toBase58()}`);
  const GREETING_SEED = 'hello';
  greetedPubkey = await web3.PublicKey.createWithSeed(
    payer.publicKey,
    GREETING_SEED,
    programId
  );
  const greetedAccount = await pg.connection.getAccountInfo(greetedPubkey);
  if (greetedAccount === null){
    console.log(
      'Creating account',
      greetedPubkey.toBase58(),
      'to say hello to,'
    );
  const lamports = await pg.connection.getMinimumBalanceForRentExemption(
    GREETING_SIZE,
  );
  const transaction = new web3.Transaction().add(
    web3.SystemProgram.createAccountWithSeed({
      fromPubkey: payer.publicKey,
      basePubkey: payer.publicKey,
      seed: GREETING_SEED,
      newAccountPubkey: greetedPubkey,
      lamports,
      space: GREETING_SIZE,
      programId
    }),
  );
  await web3.sendAndConfirmTransaction(
    pg.connection,
    transaction,
    [payer]
  );
  }
}

async function sayHello(): Promise<void> {
  try {
    console.log('Saying hello to', greetedPubkey.toBase58());
    const instruction = new web3.TransactionInstruction({
      keys: [{pubkey: greetedPubkey, isSigner: false, isWritable:true}],
      programId,
      data: Buffer.alloc(0),
    });
    const transaction = new web3.Transaction();
    transaction.add(instruction);
    console.log(transaction);
    await web3.sendAndConfirmTransaction(
      pg.connection,
      transaction,
      [payer],
    );
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error occurred:', error);
    if (error.logs) {
    console.log('Transaction logs:', error.logs);
  }
  }
}


async function main(){
  await establishPayer();
  await checkProgram();
  await sayHello();
}

main().then(
  () => {},
  err => {
    console.error(err);
  }
)


Are you using Anchor, or native Rust for the program?

I am using solana playground (native rust)

The program_id was not correct!
